# How to show that $\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{z^k}{k!}\to \mathrm e^z$ without using Cauchy product

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, exponential-function

I want to show that for $z = x +\mathrm{i}y \in\mathbb{C}$
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n\dfrac{z^i}{i!}\to \left(\sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{x^j}{j!}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{\mathrm{i}^k}{k!}\cdot y^k\right) $$ 
(wich tends itself to $\mathrm{e}^z$) as $n\to\infty$  without using the Cauchy product?
Is it possible with formal definition of the limit, to show that
$$\left\vert \sum_{i=0}^n\dfrac{(x+\mathrm{i}y)^i}{i!} - \left(\sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{x^j}{j!}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{\mathrm{i}^k}{k!}\cdot y^k\right)\right\vert \to 0 $$
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: How do you define $\exp(z)$?

Comment: I define $\exp z$ as $\exp\mathrm{Re}(z).\exp\mathrm{iIm}(z)$

Comment: And the $\exp x$ (for $x\in \mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: @Ranc Surely one can use whatever properties one wants regarding the real exponential.

Comment: uh, $\exp\mathrm{Re}(z).(\cos\mathrm{Im}(z)+\mathrm{i}\sin\mathrm{Im}(z) )$...

Comment: @GitGud, true, but this type of problems are usually very sensitive to change in boundary conditions (where *boundary conditions* are the definitions one uses :) )

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the "McLaurin series" expansion?  It is easy to see that all derivatives of $e^z$ are $e^z$ which are all equal to 1 at x= 0.  The McLaurin series expansion of $e^z$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$.  Of course, you would still need to prove that this expansion converges to $e^z$ for all z but that is easy using the fact that a power series can be differentiated "term by term".  The derivative of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nz^{n-1}}{n!}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$  (the sum now starts at n= 1 because the 0 term was 1, a constant, and its derivative is 0).  Letting m= n-1, that becomes $\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{z^m}{m!}$, the same sum as before.  That is, $y= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ satisfies $y'= y$ as well as the initial condition y(0)= 1.  And it is well known that that initial value problem has the unique solution $y= e^z$.

Comment: I can't use McLaurin expansion because, by hypothesis I must not differentiate $z\mapsto \exp z$...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the binomial expansion and show $$\left(1 + \frac{z}{N} \right)^N \rightrightarrows \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!} $$ locally uniformly in $\mathbb{C}$ (Actually, for your question i think point-wise convergence in $\mathbb{R}$ is enough).

Then note: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(x+iy)^k}{k!} \leftleftarrows \left(1 + \frac{x+iy}{N}+\frac{ixy}{N^2} \right)^N=\left(1 + \frac{x}{N} \right)^N \cdot \left(1 + \frac{iy}{N} \right)^N \rightrightarrows \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(iy)^k}{k!}$$

To show the left limit, note that there is a $O\left(\frac{1}{N^2}\right)$ term (which changes nothing).

Comment: How do you prove that $(1+z/n)^n \to \sum_{k=0}^n z^k/k!$?